# stripslash acting weird or is that normal?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a database var that contains

```
5/8\" Cabinet Grade Plywood
```

the \ being added by either WP or SQL to escape the ".

when retrieving this var i use stripslashes() both in in the value of the field used to edit that table (so that the next time someone want to edit that field he/she will see whats in that input already) and in the actual website where it suppose to appear.

The weird thing is ..

in the field it cuts from 5/8\" Cabinet Grade Plywood to just 5/8

and in the website where it suppose to appear it shows normally without slashes or anything unusual.

this is how I stripslash the field:

```
$somevar = '<input value="'.stripslashes($currentselected['something']).'" class="niceclass" name="something" type="text" />';
```

and this is how I use it when it appears on page:

```
 <td><span style="font-size: larger;"><?php echo stripslashes($goods['verygood']); ?></span></td>
```

Comment: [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to the rescue!!

Comment: :-) i will read about this right now. thanks lawrence

Comment: switch off `magic_quotes_*` and use `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it simply collides with HTML markup

```
<input value="'.stripslashes($currentselected['something']).'"/>
```

will result in

```
<input value="5/8" Cabinet Grade Plywood" />
```

take a look on those ", its broken right there, you need to escape those "

to fix this use urlencode function in php

```
<input value="'.urlencode(stripslashes($currentselected['something'])).'"/>
```

or htmlspecialchars function, it should replace quotes with

```
&quot;
```

Comment: have used :       htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($currentselected['something'])) And still cutting.

Comment: never mind it was my mistake now... probably by mistake i saved the already cut thingy to DB and didn't realize thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some `htmlspecialchars` on the output. The `"` has special meaning in HTML, and in this case would actually be seen as the closing of the `value` attribute of the `input`. Thus, you should escape it (`htmlspecialchars` will translate `"` to `&quot;`).